# Comparison method violates its general contract when I try to order contacts

Tags: java, android

I would like to compare my contacts to get an alphabetical order but I have this error :

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

This happen when I call :

```
Collections.sort(aVoid, new CustomComparator());
```

This is my CustomComparator :

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<ContactItems> {
        @Override
        public int compare(ContactItems o1, ContactItems o2) {
            if (o1.getName() == null || o2.getName() == null)
                return 0;
            else
                return o1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.getName().toLowerCase());
        }
    }
```

My `aVoid` array is the result of the method `@onPostExecute(List<ContactItems> aVoid)` of the class `AsyncTaskGetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ContactItems>>`

Comment: Can you please share how you populate the `aVoid` array?

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: You are being asked to ***show the code*** that populates `aVoid`.  NEVER describe code, always show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider three values, `A`, `B`, and `C`. Let's say `A`'s name is null, while `B` and `C`'s names are non-null **and** are different.

In your comparator, `compare(A, B)` will return 0. And `compare(A, C)` will return 0. According to the general contract of comparators, if A==B and A==C, then B==C. But that is not true for your data set. This means there is an error in your `compare` method.

You need a better method for handling nulls. Probably something like

```
public int compare(...) {
    if (o1.getName() == null && o2.getName() == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (o1.getName() == null) {
        return 1;
    } else if (o2.getName() == null) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return o1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.getName().toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: You've been faster than me. ;)